# Не отображается отладочная панель django_debug_toolbar

Tags: python, django

Есть проект на Django, который я запускаю с помощью runserver, в него я хотел добавить Django Debug Toolbar, панель которого ни под каким предлогом не хочет отображаться. Файл settings.py я настроил согласно официальным инструкциям, выполнил команду collectstatic. Даже в HTML коде своей страницы этот тулбар прогружается, но не выводится он из-за следующей ошибки:

`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Какие могут быть предложения?

Comment: А файл urls.py согласно инструкциям настроили?

Comment: Да, всё как в документации. Вообще я только сейчас увидел следующую интересную строку в доках: 'It will also only display if the MIME type of the response is either text/html or application/xhtml+xml and contains a closing </body> tag.' А у меня MIME type "text/plain". Все закрывающие теги в шаблонах вроде есть

Comment: А настройку DEBUG=True не забыли включить?

Comment: Не забыл, DEBUG установлен в True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось, адблоки могут помешать отображению `django debug toolbar`, для этого мне пришлось единоразово их выключить, `toolbar` заработал и можно включать обратно.